# How to make a list of something that implements abstract class and interface (C#)?

Tags: c#, generics

Let's say i have list of Tanks,Airplanes and many other things that the to common thing they implement is IHaveLocation which is and abstract class and IHaveColor which is an interface.

I want to make a list of them because i need to query the list on the basis of this two interfaces.

How do i do it ?

- I can make a list of objects and then write (obj as IHaveLocation) and use his methods, and (obj as IHaveColor) and use his methods. but this is very very ugly !
- I can make a list of IhaveLocation and then i need to do only one as (obj as IHaveColor). But it's also terrible
- I can create a new abstract class then inherits from both, but i'm trying to avoid it.

is there some trick to this ?

I Want to make something like `List<IHaveLocation and IHaveColor>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments of Reed's answer, you could use generic methods to allow you to add both Tank's and Airplane's.  Something like this:

```
class TwoTypesList<T1, T2>
{
    List<Tuple<T1, T2>> m_list = new List<Tuple<T1,T2>>();

    public void Add<ConcreteT>(ConcreteT item) where ConcreteT : T1, T2
    {
        m_list.Add(Tuple.Create<T1, T2>(item, item));
    }
}
```

Then the usage would be:

```
        TwoTypesList<IHaveColor, IHaveLocation> list = new TwoTypesList<IHaveColor, IHaveLocation>();
        Airplane a = new Airplane();
        Tank t = new Tank();
        list.Add(a);
        list.Add(t);
```

The downside, of course, is that you're storing the object twice.  If you don't like that, then of course you could change the internal storage of the list to be an object or only one of the interfaces.

Comment: Note that you're storing a reference to the object twice, but the object itself only exists once, so this is generally unlikely to be a problem unless you have *particularly* large lists.

Comment: @Servy, Yeah, just added an edit addressing that.  But yeah, it's a good point to keep in mind.

Answer (score 8):

You can wrap this in a generic class with constraints on both types:

```
public class YourClass<T> where T : IHaveLocation, IHaveColor
{
    List<T> items = new List<T>;

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        items.Add(item);
    }
    // ...
}
```

Methods within this class can then use both interfaces as needed, as the type is guaranteed to implement them.

Comment: Another option is to define an interface `IHaveLocationAndColor` that implements both interfaces. That won't force you to define a new class that encapsulates a standard `List<T>`.

Comment: You could derive a new collection from `Collection<T>` and use similar type constraints.

Comment: @TimothyShields The downside is that your classes have to implement that interface (`IHaveLocationAndColor`) instead of just implementing the original interfaces...

Comment: @Olly Yes, that would effectively be the same - any generic class would work, or even use a generic method on a class.

Comment: With this solution, wouldn't you have to be consistently adding an object with the same concrete type (i.e. if you had `Class1` and `Class2` that both implemented `IHaveLocation` and `IHaveColor`, then you couldn't add them both to the same `YourClass` object, right?

Comment: I'm trying to find more suitable solution, i don't like it because it's little bit weird, i think that creating an abstract class that implements both looks better. but i hoped there is even a better trick.

Comment: @MattSmith You could get around that, if you wanted to, by storing via the interface in the list, or even object.

Comment: @ReedCopsey, Yes, but you couldn't have the type T be the concrete class, right?  In his example, he wants to store different concrete types "Tanks, airplanes, and other things".

Comment: @ReedCopsey, In other words, I'm thinking the genericity, should be at the method level (on the Add), not on the class.

Comment: @MattSmith Yes, you could do that to work around it.  You'd have to make all of your methods generic, though, if you want to store multiple concrete types in there.  It's a bit odd to work that way, but it'd work.  Depends on what the requiremetns are, though.

Comment: Now i want to create an instance from this class, how do i do it , what should i pass as T ? I can't pass airplane or tank because it won't work with the other type

Comment: @OopsUser That was Matt's point - if you want to support BOTH in one instance, using generic methods instead of a generic class would work.  It just gets ugly quickly.

Comment: But the class has only one list .. i have a class that makes collision detection for all the items in the game, and it stores the items in one list ...  even if i make my methods generic, the list has to have some kind of type .. and i want to avoid using Object

Comment: @OopsUser, you could also use a List of Tuples in the class, where the tuple stores the same object but as different types.  I'm not sure that would be any better than using `object` or one of the Interfaces, as it would just ensure type safety internally to the class. As said before, it depends entirely on the requirements, but I think you have the pieces you need.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like :

```
public class YourClass<T> where T : Ihavelocation, ihavecolor{
    List<T> items = new List<T>;

    public void Add(T item){
        items.Add(item);
    }

}
```